# Unit test with a Marionette.CompositeView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, marionette

By using `jasmine`, I am trying to test a javascript module which returns a `Marionette.CompositeView`.

Here are the javascript module(2) and the javascript unit-test(1).

My question is how to access the rendered view from the (1)?
Please see the comment on the code for more details.

P.S.:
1) The javascript module works producing the right rendered view.
2) When I run the test, the javascript console gives me the following error: `backbone.marionette.min.js:9`

```
Uncaught NoTemplateError: Could not find template: 'function (context, options) {
    if (!compiled) {
      compiled = compile();
    }
    return compiled.call(this, context, options);
  }'
```

3) Since I am using `handlebars` I rewrote the `Marionette.Renderer.render` in this way:

```
enter code here
define([
    'marionette'
], function (Marionette) {
    Marionette.Renderer.render = function (template, data) {
        return template(data);
    };
});
```

---

(1)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    define([
        // some code
    ], function (MyView) {
        describe('Layout App - Header View ', function () {
            beforeEach(function () {
                this.view = new MyView({
                    currentUser: new Backbone.Model()
                });
            });

            describe('Instantiation', function () {
                it('should create a div element', function () {
                    expect(this.view.el.nodeName).toEqual('DIV'); // it works
                });

            });

            describe("Rendering", function () {

                it("returns the view object", function () {
                    console.log(this.view.render()); // undefined // why?
                    expect(this.view.render()).toEqual(this.view); // it fails
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

---

(2)

```
define([
    // some code
], function (myTemplate, MyItemView) {
    return Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        template: myTemplate,
        itemView: MyItemView,
        // some code
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

call the `render` method on it, like you would with any other backbone view

```
            beforeEach(function () {
                this.view = new MyView({
                    currentUser: new Backbone.Model()
                });

                // render it
                this.view.render();
            });
```

Comment: Hi Derick, thanks for your reply. Actually, your suggestion does not fix the issue, yet. Anyway I added more info about my question. Please see the section `P.S.`, the points 2 and 3

Answer (score 0):

The render method does, in fact, return `undefined`. Instead of `expect(this.view.render())`, you should do something like

`this.view.render();
expect(this.view.$el.find('.class_in_template').length).to.be.greaterThan(0);`